# howto convert excel date to normal m/d/y format php

Tags: php, excel, date

any simple way to convert **DATE** fetched from excel sheet to normal m/d/y format

```
43553
43542
43534
```

im using:

```
date( "m/d/Y", mktime( 0,0,0,1,$date-1,1900 ) );
```

any easy way other than this!!

Comment: could be adding the number to the "basedate" of excel (not sure if this is 1.1.1900 or 31.12.1899 - or even 1904 - there is a "mac" special case)

Comment: 1900 01 01 is the date in Excel. Do you know what the dates should be? Can you convert them in Excel and post it to us?

Comment: date("m/d/Y", mktime(0,0,0,1,$date-1,1900));  any easy way to find it

Comment: `03/29/2019, 03/18/2019, 03/10/2019`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this below code to get normal date format from your excel date.

```
$excel_date = 43534; 

//convert excel date to unix date format  
$unix_date = ($excel_date - 25569) * 86400;

// Now convert it into human readable format
$normal_date = gmdate("m/d/Y", $unix_date);
```

output of the above code will be 03/10/2019